# How to change the stroke colour in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape

Sorry for this extremely basic question. I am wondering if my version of Inkscape is buggy or something...

I draw a line and want to change its colour. How?

This is what I have tried:

Open Fill and Stroke -> stroke tab -> selecting the solid colour square -> clicking a colour

Occasionally (that is why I wonder if it is a buggy release), but I don't see any pattern, the colour of my line has changed but typically it only change the fill of the line.

Edit: sorry, I was unclear. What happens when I change colour (as described above) is that, in the lower left corner, where you have a colour "legend" with two entries - *stroke* and *fill* - the fill entry changes colour, in spite of me working in the *stroke* tab in the *Fill and Stroke* panel. Unsurprisingly, the colour of the line doesn't change when this happens.

Here is a screenshot of what is going on:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFWgS.jpg]

Comment: You are only changing the fill colour. Use shift+click to choose the stroke colour.  A fill won't show on a single straight line segment. This isn't a bug.

Comment: @BillyKerr Aah, not a bug but questionable UI!

Comment: No. It's just a shortcut.

Comment: @BillyKerr Do you mean that there is there another, more intuitive, way to change the stroke colour than using a modifier key?

Comment: No I didn't say that. Generally I've found that the more complex the software is, the less intuitive it is.  Inkscape's UI may at first glance look simple, but in reality it's complex, not intuitive, but then so are most complex design tools. They all have a steep learning curve.

Comment: @BillyKerr What did you mean with "just a shortcut"? Usually a shortcut is a faster way to do something that can be done in another, more elaborate, way.

Comment: I mean Shift+clicking on a colour in the colour palette along the bottom is the keyboard shortcut to add a stroke of a specific colour to a path, rather than going through the Stroke and Fill panel.

Comment: @BillyKerr But how would you do it using the the Stroke and Fill panel? As you can see in my screen recording, that is what I tried first.

Comment: Did you not read my answer. It shows exactly that.

Comment: @BillyKerr Did you watch my screen rcording?

Comment: Yes of course I watched it. In your recording you are changing the fill colour, not the stroke colour.

Comment: @BillyKerr I don't see what I do differently from you. I have the stroke panel and the solid colour option selected when I change the colour, just like you seem to have it setup. Still the stroke doesn't change.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have an object selected and you click a color in the bottom palette it will be the new fill color. Shift+Click picks a color and puts it to the stroke. It's written in the guidance text in the bottom.

I have version 0.92.4

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to suggest you check out some basic tutorials on youtube. I think you would really benefit from following a few. Everyone has to start somewhere!

Anyway, this isn't a tutorial, but hopefully there's enough information below to get you started.

1. Select an object
2. Open the Fill and Stroke dialog <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
3. Select the Stroke Paint tab
4. Choose the "Flat colour" square. This adds a stroke to the path.
5. If nothing shows up, the stroke is probably just too thin to be seen. If so, click on the Stroke Style tab, and increase the stroke width
6. In the Stroke Paint tab, choose a colour

Note: you can select lots of stroke styles in the Stroke Style tab, such as dashes, markers, caps, joins etc, etc.

Example showing changing the fill, stroke paint, and stroke style.

[image]

Comment: What software did you use to create the animation in your answer?

Comment: @d-b screen capture software called ShareX

Comment: Today I got a notification that this question has been viewed 10 000 times. Clearly it is not just me who bumped into this problem :-)

Comment: @d-b - oh cool.  Hopefully it helped some of them!

Answer (score 0):

After you choose Flat Color.
There are 6 tabs to choose how you want to pick the color.
RGB HSL HSV CMYK Wheel CMS
If you are using 1.0beta, yes it is buggy.
I found this video that my clear things up.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o86MLSQHtMg